# scope variable inside object does not get updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an issue where my `$scope.searchVal` variable updates, but if I assign it inside an object, it doesn't seem to update at all.

See below:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div>{{searchVal}}</div>    
  <div>{{searchFilter}}</div>    
  <div>
      <input ng-model="searchVal"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/for3v3rforgott3n/be6s1eLo/1/)

If I type in the input, the first `div`'s value updates properly for `searchVal`, but the `searchFilter` object that contains `$scope.searchVal` as a value is set to the original value of `''` and does not update accordingly.

I've considered (and tried) updating the whole object everytime I need it by calling a function, but this seems really hacky to me. Is there a simple way to get this done? Am I missing something?

Comment: `"search": $scope.searchVal` only evaluates once at startup. You'd have to use something like `$scope.$watch`, `ngChange`, or turning it into a function like you mentioned.

Comment: @AnthonyChu I see, thanks. I'm still pretty new to this all so I thought maybe I was doing something stupid and there was a way to get Angular to do it for me.

Comment: As @AnthonyChu suggested, a ng-change on the input box is a better approach. Something like: `$scope.update = function(value) {$scope.searchFilter.search = value; };`

Answer (score 0):

What you have to is `$watch` the value from the scope something like:

**[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/be6s1eLo/2/)**

```
$scope.$watch('searchVal',function(newVal, oldVal){
     $scope.searchFilter.search = newVal;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't as straighforward as it seems since angular has no way of knowing whether you want the dynamic binding for the property or not.

You can achieve what you are trying to do using $watch service. Put a watch on the searchVal & use it to detect changes & update the object property accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Please put $watch . It will always watch the value change of variable

```
$scope.$watch('searchVal',function(newVal, oldVal){
     $scope.searchFilter.search = newVal;
});
```

[updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/be6s1eLo/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/be6s1eLo/3/)

Comment: How does this add up to the answer already provided 7 hours before this one? Aren't up votes made to support answers that we think are correct instead of duplicating answers or copying over?